# Implement JavaScript Buffer to store data

Tags: javascript, arrays, buffer, framebuffer

I receive these huge Strings via WebSocket:

```
[
  "BTC-31DEC21-100000-P",
  "{\"data\":{\"bids\":{\"0.01\":{\"price\":0.01,\"volume\":66.2,\"exchange\":\"DER\"},\"5.0E-4\":{\"price\":5.0E-4,\"volume\":1.1,\"exchange\":\"DER\"},\"0.637\":{\"price\":0.637,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\"}},\"asks\":{\"0.664\":{\"price\":0.664,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\"}}},\"isMasterFrame\":true}"
]
```

or

```
[
  "BTC-31DEC21-36000-C",
  "{\"data\":[{\"price\":0.422,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.423,\"volume\":0.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"}],\"isMasterFrame\":false}"
]
```

or

```
[
  "BTC-31DEC21-60000-P",
  "{\"data\":[{\"price\":0.105,\"volume\":0.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.1055,\"volume\":28.7,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.106,\"volume\":7.6,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.1065,\"volume\":43.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"}],\"isMasterFrame\":false}"
]
```

I want to make JavaScript Buffer where I can store the data and reset it if I receive JSON with `isMasterFrame` = true

```js
let payload = JSON.parse(messageString[1]);

if (payload.hasOwnProperty("isMasterFrame")) {
  for (let i = 0; i < payload.pairs.length; i++) {
    let currentPair = payload.data[i]
    currentPair = currentPair.replace(/\0/g, ''); //Remove null chars
    if (currentPair.toUpperCase() != 'KILL') {
      // reset the buffer and start again to fill data
    }
  }
} else {
  // if we receive "isMasterFrame":false just update the data without reset
}
```

What are the available options to implement this buffer?

Comment: Why not `if(payload.data.isMasterFrame) { ... }`, and where is the `pairs` property in the data (did I miss it)? It also appears the _reset_ is conditional upon the `currentPair` not being equal to `KILL`. Is that true?

Comment: other than those clarifcations, it is as simple as creating a cache array (`let pairsCache = [];`, then `.push()` onto the array if not a masterframe and not KILL otherwise set the cache array back to `pairsCache = []`;

Comment: you're right. This is is just and example from other code. Can you show me code example please for the solution?

Comment: Can you please provided a data sample that contains "KILL" ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are after. It caches the details until it finds `isMasterFrame: true` && `KILL`, at which time it clears the cache and starts over again.

EDIT: Stored data using BTC style string as key and data as value to enable querying cache.

```js
let messageCache = {};
const messages = [
  ["BTC-31DEC21-36000-C", "{\"data\":[{\"price\":0.422,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.423,\"volume\":0.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"}],\"isMasterFrame\":false}"],
  ["BTC-31DEC21-36000-D", "{\"data\":[{\"price\":0.422,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.423,\"volume\":0.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"}],\"isMasterFrame\":false}"],
  ["BTC-31DEC21-60000-P", "{\"data\":[{\"price\":0.105,\"volume\":0.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.1055,\"volume\":28.7,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.106,\"volume\":7.6,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.1065,\"volume\":43.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"KILL\"}],\"isMasterFrame\"\:true}"],
  ["BTC-31DEC21-60000-Q", "{\"data\":[{\"price\":0.105,\"volume\":0.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.1055,\"volume\":28.7,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.106,\"volume\":7.6,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.1065,\"volume\":43.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"}],\"isMasterFrame\"\:false}"]
];

function processData(key, payload) {
  if (!payload.isMasterFrame) {
    messageCache[key] = payload; 
    return;
  }
  for (let obj of payload.data) {
    Object.values(obj).forEach(item => {
      item = item.toString().replace(/\0/g, ''); //Remove null chars
      if (item.toUpperCase() !== 'KILL') {
        messageCache = {}; // Clear the cache/buffer
      }
    });
  }
}

function queryCache(key){
   return messageCache[key];
}

messages.forEach(message => {
  const payload = JSON.parse(message[1]);
  processData(message[0], payload);
  console.log("Number of cached messages: " + Object.keys(messageCache).length);
});

console.log('Query Cache [BTC-31DEC21-60000-Q]:');
let result = queryCache('BTC-31DEC21-60000-Q');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I will check it. By the way one additional question. I expect this code to consume too much memory. Is it possible to use more efficient memory structure? Also can you show me how I can query the data?

Comment: For example for `BTC-31DEC21-36000-C` I want to get all available data from the buffer.

Comment: Please address the memory consumption in a different question SO. It is frowned upon to ask multiple questions in one. I recommend you discover if you have a memory issue prior to assuming you will.

Comment: In order to query on that string, that code needs to change. You were not clear about what was to go into the "buffer", so I didn't included that string. The code needs to change, I'll get to it soon.

Comment: @user1285928 - Answer has been edited to allow querying. Please accept ✓ this answer if you find it helpful. Thanks.